# Find the start time of each set of actions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

```
NO  ACTION_DT           REQUEST_TYPE STATUS_CD  
34  12/5/2007 6:57:04 PM    CREATE  APPROVED    
34  1/10/2012 2:53:49 PM    DELETE  PENDING 
34  1/10/2012 3:00:00 PM    DELETE  DENIED  
34  1/7/2013 9:42:33 AM     DELETE  APPROVED
```

I would like to create a start_dt based on criteria.

I need the first value for request_start_date after a status code of "approved" or "denied"

"Approved" or "denied" indicates the end of a request. The following rows should have the first rows action_dt until an approved or denied is met.

Expected output:

```
NO  ACTION_DT               REQUEST_TYPE    STATUS_CD   REQUEST_START_DT
34  12/5/2007 6:57:04 PM    CREATE          APPROVED    12/5/2007 6:57:04 PM    
34  1/10/2012 2:53:49 PM    DELETE          PENDING     1/10/2012 2:53:49 PM  
34  1/10/2012 3:00:00 PM    DELETE          DENIED      1/10/2012 2:53:49 
34  1/7/2013 9:42:33 AM     DELETE          APPROVED    1/7/2013 9:42:33 AM
```

Code:

```
select *,
CASE
WHEN W.REQUEST_TYPE IN ('CREATE','UPDATE','RELEASE','DELETE','HOLD') AND    W.STATUS_CD IN ('NEW') THEN W.ACTION_DT
WHEN W.REQUEST_TYPE IN ('CREATE','UPDATE','RELEASE','DELETE','HOLD') AND W.STATUS_CD IN ('PENDING','NEW','DENIED','APPROVED')  AND LAG(W.ACTION_USER)   OVER (PARTITION BY W.NO ORDER BY W.ACTION_DT) IS NULL THEN W.ACTION_DT
--WHEN W.REQUEST_TYPE IN ('CREATE','UPDATE','RELEASE','DELETE','HOLD') AND W.STATUS_CD NOT IN ('NEW') THEN (CASE WHEN W.STATUS_CD IN ('APPROVED','DENIED')   THEN LAG(W.ACTION_DT) 
--OVER (PARTITION BY W.NO,W.REQUEST_TYPE ORDER BY W.ACTION_DT)END)
 WHEN LAG(W.STATUS_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY W.NO ORDER BY W.ACTION_DT)

  /*WHEN W.REQUEST_TYPE IN ('CREATE','UPDATE','RELEASE','DELETE','HOLD') AND W.STATUS_CD NOT IN ('NEW') THEN LAG(CASE WHEN W.STATUS_CD IN ('APPROVED','DENIED') THEN W.ACTION_DT END )
  --,ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND PRECEDING )
 OVER (PARTITION BY W.NO ORDER BY W.ACTION_DT) */

  ELSE NULL
--ELSE W.ACTION_DT
  END REQUEST_START_DT
  from w
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE W ( NO, ACTION_DT, REQUEST_TYPE, STATUS_CD ) AS
SELECT 34, DATE '2007-12-05' + INTERVAL '18:57:04' HOUR TO SECOND, 'CREATE', 'APPROVED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 34, DATE '2012-01-10' + INTERVAL '14:53:49' HOUR TO SECOND, 'DELETE', 'PENDING'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 34, DATE '2012-01-10' + INTERVAL '15:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 'DELETE', 'DENIED'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 34, DATE '2013-01-07' + INTERVAL '09:42:33' HOUR TO SECOND, 'DELETE', 'APPROVED' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

Use the `COUNT` analytic function to get a cumulative count to the number of `APPROVED` or `DENIED` rows to give you something to group the rows by:

```sql
SELECT W.*,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN STATUS_CD IN ( 'APPROVED', 'DENIED' ) THEN 1 END )
         OVER ( PARTITION BY NO ORDER BY ACTION_DT )
         + CASE WHEN STATUS_CD IN ( 'APPROVED', 'DENIED' ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
         AS grp
FROM   w
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> NO | ACTION_DT           | REQUEST_TYPE | STATUS_CD | GRP
> -: | :------------------ | :----------- | :-------- | --:
> 34 | 2007-12-05 18:57:04 | CREATE       | APPROVED  |   1
> 34 | 2012-01-10 14:53:49 | DELETE       | PENDING   |   2
> 34 | 2012-01-10 15:00:00 | DELETE       | DENIED    |   2
> 34 | 2013-01-07 09:42:33 | DELETE       | APPROVED  |   3
> ```

You can then use this to find the minimum `ACTION_DT` for each group:

```sql
SELECT no,
       action_dt,
       request_type,
       status_cd,
       MIN( action_dt ) OVER ( PARTITION BY no, grp ) AS request_start_dt
FROM   (
  SELECT W.*,
         COUNT( CASE WHEN STATUS_CD IN ( 'APPROVED', 'DENIED' ) THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY NO ORDER BY ACTION_DT )
           + CASE WHEN STATUS_CD IN ( 'APPROVED', 'DENIED' ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
           AS grp
  FROM   w
)
ORDER BY action_dt
```

**Output**:

> ```
> NO | ACTION_DT           | REQUEST_TYPE | STATUS_CD | REQUEST_START_DT   
> -: | :------------------ | :----------- | :-------- | :------------------
> 34 | 2007-12-05 18:57:04 | CREATE       | APPROVED  | 2007-12-05 18:57:04
> 34 | 2012-01-10 14:53:49 | DELETE       | PENDING   | 2012-01-10 14:53:49
> 34 | 2012-01-10 15:00:00 | DELETE       | DENIED    | 2012-01-10 14:53:49
> 34 | 2013-01-07 09:42:33 | DELETE       | APPROVED  | 2013-01-07 09:42:33
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=649fd57c0a0a1c4b3efb12d3886ca580)*

Comment: I don't understand the + CASE WHEN STATUS_CD IN ( 'APPROVED', 'DENIED' ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END. I mean, it works but I would like to understand this piece.

Comment: @John In row 2 there has been only one `APPROVED` row previously but your requirements are that it be grouped with the next row (not the previous one) so by adding one to the value of the group it changes it from being grouped with the previous `APPROVED` row to the next `DENIED` row.